# java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB in Views

Tags: java, android

This piece of code causes me `java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB` error, any idea why? I am trying to have TableLayout and TableRow inside NestedScrollView.

```
String testString = "test";
tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
TextView textInRow = new TextView(this)
TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
textInRow.setText(testString);
tableRow.addView(tableRow);
tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
```

here is my activity xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="eu.martinbednar.mayak.TripList"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling"
    android:id="@+id/table">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:isScrollContainer="true">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hard to say, but I guess this

```
tableRow.addView(tableRow);
```

may be the cause. Adding the view to itself it is probably cause of a infinite recursion, hence the `StackOverflowError`

Comment: Recursion was the cause in my case

Answer (score 0):

```
    String testString = "test";
    tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
    TextView textInRow = new TextView(this)
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
    textInRow.setText(testString);
    tableRow.addView(textInRow);
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
```

Use this instead.